# How to add an array into a comma delimited text file without deleting previous array values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to make a form where the user can add their own 'questions + answers' to the quiz.

I loaded the original questions from a text file. The added questions will then be processed by **process_editadd.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$file = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
$array=$_SESSION['questions_array'];

//make array out of values
$q=array($_POST['question'],$_POST['one'],$_POST['two'],$_POST['three'],$_POST['four']);
//add to file
$file=fopen("data.txt","w+");
fwrite($file, implode(',', $q)).

header('Location:module.php');

?>
```

The array adds onto the text file, but the problem is that it *replaces* the whole thing. I don't want the questions to replace the previous ones, I just want them added. Do you guys know what's wrong with the code?

**Note:** I'm not allowed using mySQL or Javascript

Comment: Please trim down to only the **relevant** code.

Answer (score 1):

You could switch to using an actual database and make your life a lot easier... Failing that, look into [fputcsv](http://php.net/fputcsv) and [fgetcsv](http://php.net/fgetcsv) to make it a slightly less tedious problem.

Your implode version right now is also vulnerable to CSV injection... you don't handle the case where any of the text you're writing  MIGHT contain a comma. If it does, you'll suddenly find you'll have extra "columns" when you read the data back in later on.

Comment: The thing is, I'm not allowed to use mySQL or java. :[ I'm not worried about the comma thing right now as this isn't a very serious project, but I'll look into the fputcsv. Thanks!